# how to change sec-ch-ua-platform in selenium4 with c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to change the information of this section in Chrome for my traffic robot, but no changes are made.
How can I change these parameters? My code is written based on Selenium 4.
According to the following address, I want to break the --user-agent limit and change other header parameters in Selenium so that the traffic is organic and different.
--sec-ch-ua-platform
--sec-ch-ua
...

```
            string Url = "https://whatismyipaddress.com/";
            ChromeOptions ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            
            ChromeOptions.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors"); 
             ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--sec-ch-ua-platform=Android");
                ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--sec-ch-ua-mobile=?1");
            ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--sec-ch-ua=Chromium\"; v = \"110\", \"Not A(Brand\"; v = \"23\", \"Google Chrome\"; v = \"109");
            ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19");
            /// disable image
            ChromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-images");
            ChromeOptions.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
           
            ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);

            //MainMenu code
            driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
```

i use this url code and convert it to c# but dosnt work
[How to set User-Agent Client Hint sec-ch-ua in Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668952/how-to-set-user-agent-client-hint-sec-ch-ua-in-selenium-python)
I even tried changing other header parameters but it didn't work.

```
string sec_ch_ua = "\"Examplary Browser\"; v=\"73\", \";Not?A.Brand\"; v=\"27\"";

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument($"--sec-ch-ua={sec_ch_ua}");
  //ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--sec-ch-ua-platform=Android");
  //ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent-platform=Android");
```

Comment: i use this url and convert code to c# but dosnt change in header
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668952/how-to-set-user-agent-client-hint-sec-ch-ua-in-selenium-python

string sec_ch_ua = "\"Examplary Browser\"; v=\"73\", \";Not?A.Brand\"; v=\"27\"";

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument($"--sec-ch-ua={sec_ch_ua}");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("chromedriver.exe", options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://user-agent-client-hints.glitch.me/");